ADB error -3001: INSTALL_FAILED_REJECTED_BY_BUILDTYPE
I've been trying to reinstall Samsung Clock Style which I believe is a system application.
When trying to, it gives the output "adb: failed to install : Failure [-3001: INSTALL_FAILED_REJECTED_BY_BUILDTYPE]"
I try to install the package with the code ./adb install -r -d 
I've tried many different package versions with different signatures and architectures but no dice.
